# Ant-Based Versioning

Tags: java, ant, build

I'd like to know if "Ant-based versioning" is possible, or something like it. Here's what I mean:

A common naming convention for JARs is something like `MyJar-1.0.14.jar`, where `MyJar` is the primary name of the JAR file, and the `-1.0.14` represents the version number.

In my Ant buildscript, I'm going to have a task `dist` that will look *something* like:

```
<target name="dist" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/MyJar.jar">
        <!-- All the filesets to JAR up -->
    </jar>
</target>
```

My question is: does Ant support *anything* that would automatically update the JARs name with the correct version number per some external scheme?  Something so that the Ant target might actually look like:

```
<target name="dist" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/MyJar-[revision].jar">
        <!-- All the filesets to JAR up -->
    </jar>
</target>
```

Where `[revision]` is the build/revision number according to some internally-defined revision scheme (perhaps defined in some other external file)?

If so, then if I am to understand my situation, then I am stuck modifying the build.xml file every time I want to JAR-up a new version of my distribution? Yes? No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not aware of any ant task to auto-increment the number, but you should defined the revision as a property in a build.properties file which you'll import. The property file will contain a default value

```
revision=1.0
```

in the ant build.xml file

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
<target>
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/MyJar-${revision}.jar>
```

To update the property at build time you just call the ant target with the -D value set

```
ant -Drevision=2.0 dist
```

this avoids the need to update any file at release time.

Comment: I agree this is the easiest way of achieving the result, but a related question comes up: what would users expect for an incremental build; i.e., where a clean hasn't been done?  Should we attempt to remove old versions of the jar file or should we just accumulate them?

Answer (score 4):

There is an ant task which will increment the build number. Its called buildNumber

Read, increment, and write a build number to the default file, build.number.

```
<buildnumber file="mybuild.number"/>`
```

[buildNumber.html](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html)

Our ant processing goes something like this

1 - Version control update the build file

2 - Increment the build number

3 - Check/commit in the build number

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property and use it like that:

```
<jar destfile="${dist.dir}/MyJar-${revision}.jar">
```